# Is it possible to have multiple/unlimited entries per group type in BuddyPress profiles?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm considering using BuddyPress for a profiles section of a website. It looks pretty good so far, before I get to far into it, I'm wondering if I can have multiple entries for each 'profile group' form.. For example (using the testbp.org install), on the profile edit form you can click the 'work' section and fill out company/job title/job description - this is good, but without a tonne of extending the code, can they have unlimited 'work' entries to create a job history or is it normally just one?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It's normal just one - but it can be extended easily via custom code.